# Hello world OpenGL Kotlin app with kotlinc for Android on Mac, or with Gradle and Java

Tags: java, android, opengl, kotlin

I have installed android with the [latest stuff](https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03):

```
brew install ant
brew install maven
brew install gradle
brew install android-sdk
brew install android-ndk
brew install kotlin
```

I have a simple hello world `example.kt` file like this:

```
package foo.bar

fun ms() : Long {
  return System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

And a `test.kt` like this:

```
package foo.bar

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(ms())
}
```

which is compiled and run like this:

```
kotlinc src -include-runtime -d test.jar
kotlin test.jar
```

Next I would like to display a triangle using OpenGL on Android. A basic hello world example. I've checked through quite a few resources but haven't seen how to actually compile an *Activity* using `kotlinc`, which seems like the main "application object" in Android.

- https://github.com/egslava/example-Kotlin-Android-GLSurfaceView
- https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle
- https://github.com/jvm-graphics-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/gl4/helloTriangle.kt
- https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/opengl/src/openglMain/kotlin/OpenGlTeapot.kt
- https://github.com/egslava/example-Kotlin-Android-GLSurfaceView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/egslava/tutorialglsurfaceview/MainActivity.kt
- https://github.com/bnlrnz/MandelGL
- https://github.com/bnlrnz/MandelGL/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/tubaf/mandelGL/MandelGLRenderer.kt
- https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/android-kotlin-vs-java-by-example-part-1-simple-hello-world-a899inz3o
- https://medium.com/@passsy/starting-activities-with-kotlin-my-journey-8b7307f1e460
- https://medium.com/@FizzyInTheHall/building-an-android-activity-from-scratch-with-kotlin-a5c0f5b6520a
- [Kotlin Android start new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518139/kotlin-android-start-new-activity)
- https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html
- https://github.com/JimSeker/opengl/blob/master/HelloOpenGLES20/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/opengl/Triangle.java
- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/opengl/GLES20
- https://github.com/ligee/kotlin-ndk-samples/blob/master/native-codec/src/com/example/nativecodec/MyGLSurfaceView.kt
- [Why shouldn't an Android app be written in C/C++ because you "simply prefer to program in C/C++"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773686/why-shouldnt-an-android-app-be-written-in-c-c-because-you-simply-prefer-to-p)
- https://github.com/JimSeker/opengl/blob/master/HelloOpenGLES32/app/src/main/java/edu/cs4730/helloopengles32/Triangle.java
- https://tutorialwing.com/android-textureview-using-kotlin-with-example/
- https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/kotlindemos/MainActivity.kt
- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

For reference, these imports seem relevant to android sdk OpenGL:

```
import android.opengl.GLES20
import android.opengl.GLES32
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
```

Anyways, basically what this boils down to is *how to render an Activity using kotlinc*, purely from the command line, without Android Studio or any UI/IDE. Once I get there then I can figure out how to do OpenGL.

So for example, [this](https://proandroiddev.com/modern-android-development-with-kotlin-september-2017-part-1-f976483f7bd6) post shows this Activity boilerplate:

```
package me.mladenrakonjac.modernandroidapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

I would like to just render a HelloWorld Activity (without any AndroidManifest.xml if possible, just Kotlin instead of XML, unless XML is required, I'm new to Android), from the command line. Not sure how to take that `MainActivity` snippet and compile it and render it, maybe add a textarea with "hello world" in it.

If not possible with Kotlin, then wondering how to do it with Gradle/Java.

Comment: ***WOW*** you have gone hardcore compliance (to be expected ;O)) Seems simple, you will get a lot of answers I'm sure ;o)

Comment: Why not use Android Studio to write down the code? Feel free to use the command line for compilation and building afterwards.

Comment: While you're trying to dig a channel with spoon, I'll tell you that even if you manage to build `apk` file `without AndroidManifest.xml` you won't be able to install and run the application without the `xml`.

Comment: My answer to the question [“Hello world” Android app with as few files as possible, no IDE, and text editor only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167769/hello-world-android-app-with-as-few-files-as-possible-no-ide-and-text-editor/47251607#47251607) should help here. You can write in pure c/C++ no **java/kotlin** *at all* if your familiar with NDK/JNI.